# Starting JAXWS servlet at root of the web context?

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis, web.xml

Is it possible to start JAXWS servlet at the roor of the web contex, so that the WSDL will be also accessible?

My context root, defined in application.xml is `/myapp/webservice/v1` (the last part should be configurable in the deployment descriptor, and the web service should be available in web context root).

I've tried:

```xml
<servlet>
    <display-name>WebService</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.WebServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The WebService answers under the address `/myapp/webservice/v1`, but when I type `/myapp/webservice/v1?wsdl`, it's converted into `/myapp/webservice/v1/?wsdl`, which doesn't return WSDL, but it tries to invoke the WebService itself, which answers: "Hello! This is an Axis2 Web Service!" (standard greeting when doing GET to WebService).

I've tried also with url pattern '.'. '*' and '/*' are not accepted (WebSphere).

When I use

```xml
    <url-pattern>ws</url-pattern>
```

and

```xml
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>ws</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

the web service works, but the WSDL is available only on `/myapp/webservice/v1/ws?wsdl`, which makes the solution incompatibile with existing clients.

The reason behind is to create version as separate WARs, which can be then deployed independently or within EAR, and to make WebService address fully configurable, we need to make it accessible under the context root of the Web Module.

I don't know if the problems we are experiencing are WebSphere-specific or Axis-specific...

Comment: Which version of WebSphere are you using?

Comment: @PaulVargas WebSphere 7